# I accidently disabled the ubuntu servers public network interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

I accidently disabled the servers public network interface using the below command

Ifdown ens192

I am not able to access the server now. Is there any way to get the interface back up?

Comment: Log into the (virtual) console and restart the interface or reboot the server if your provider doesn’t offer a remote out-of-band management console

Comment: Thanks will try that

Answer (score 0):

Do you have serial access? You can try accessing VM using serial and after getting serial console access, enable networking.